# Django ORM Query or raw SQL Query

Tags: sql, django, django-models, subquery, django-queryset

I need to make a query, where I can display the total amount of clothes ordered by clients, the result should be like this:

Client_1 | Cloth_Type_X_SUM | Cloth_Type_Y_SUM | Cloth_Type_Z_SUM | SUM_ALL
Client_2 | Cloth_Type_X_SUM | Cloth_Type_Y_SUM | Cloth_Type_Z_SUM | SUM_ALL
Client_3 | Cloth_Type_X_SUM | Cloth_Type_Y_SUM | Cloth_Type_Z_SUM | SUM_ALL

models.py

```
class Cloth(models.Model):
    description = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    type = models.CharField(max_length=2)

class Order(models.Model):
    client = models.ForeignKey(Client, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

class Order_Detail(models.Model):
    order = models.ForeignKey(Order, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    cloth = models.ForeignKey(Cloth, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    weight = models.FloatField()
```

The closest that I got was:

```
Order_Detail.objects.values('order__client__name','cloth__type').annotate(Sum('weight'))
```

The problem with this is that it will retrieve an object for each cloth type:

```
Client_1 | Cloth_Type_X | SUM_X
Client_1 | Cloth_Type_Y | SUM_Y
Client_1 | Cloth_Type_Z | SUM_Z
Client_2 | Cloth_Type_X | SUM_X
Client_2 | Cloth_Type_Y | SUM_Y
Client_2 | Cloth_Type_Z | SUM_Z
Client_3 | Cloth_Type_X | SUM_X
Client_3 | Cloth_Type_Y | SUM_Y
Client_3 | Cloth_Type_Z | SUM_Z
```

Isn't there a better approach?

Comment: Are you trying to get the weight group by clients ?

Comment: Yes, but not only the total weight, but the SUM of the weights for each cloth type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [**`Conditional Expressions`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/conditional-expressions/) for that purpose

```
Order_Detail.objects.values('order__client').annotate(
   cloth_type_x_sum = Sum(Case(When(cloth__type=X, then='weight'))), 
   cloth_type_y_sum = Sum(Case(When(cloth__type=Y, then='weight'))),
   cloth_type_z_sum = Sum(Case(When(cloth__type=Z, then='weight'))),
).order_by('order__client')
```

Comment: Excellent, this is exactly what I needed! Thanks bro!

Answer (score 0):

```
from django.db.models import Sum
Order_Detail.objects.values('cloth').annotate(cloth_weight=Sum('weight'))
```

This will give you grouped by cloth type.

```
Order_Detail.objects.values('order__client').annotate(cloth_weight=Sum('weight'))
```

This will give yougrouped by client.

Comment: Yes, but in different object values, I need to have it in the same object result. The result should be like this:

client_1 | cloth_type_x_sum | cloth_type_Y_sum | cloth_type_z_sum | sum_total